# Dynamic Value for @DiscriminatorColumn

Tags: java, jpa, inheritance, eclipselink, discriminator

is it possible to provide a dynamic value (e.g. from a variable) for a jpa @DiscriminatorColumn?

For example, there is this entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "topic")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(
    discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.INTEGER, name = "topic_type_id")
public class Topic {

   @Transient
   private Integer type_id
```

I tried to set topic_type_id dynamically by providing a @DiscriminatorFormula like this:

```
@DiscriminatorFormula("CASE WHEN type_id IS NOT NULL THEN type_id end")
```

But this does not work like intended.
Does anyone have an idea how to provide a dynamic value for a DiscriminatorColumn?

Comment: since `type_id` is transient, it is useless in a "sql formula".. please have a look at [Example 5 of hibernate's "Inheritance" chapter](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.1/userguide/html_single/chapters/domain/inheritance.html#entity-inheritance-single-table-discriminator-formula-example)

Comment: thx for the link @xerx593. I see that my approach will not work. Do you have an idea on how to dynamically set the discriminator value? In the examples provided by the link, the values are always hard coded strings.

Comment: generally the question is good & interesting: "is it possible to provide a dynamic value (e.g. from a variable) for a jpa @DiscriminatorColumn?" ..and i would agree with CodeBlind: it is not possible (to bring any dynamic value into any (java)annotation).. but to achieve the functionality you wish (designate one entities type "at creation time"), you still can "go with @DiscriminatorColumn", and just need to set the correct (constant, discriminator) value (before save) ..or let do hibernate it for you (by instantiating the correct non-abstract object (with constant discr.value))

Comment: Have you seen https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Entities/Inheritance#.40ClassExtractor ? you can define a method to handle this determination yourself from the database row. The problem usually isn't on reading in though, but on what to write out. You might want to put out a more specific example of what you need done - what level of non-static do you need, as the classes themselves have to be available anyway.

Comment: @xerx593 what do you mean by set the correct (constant, discriminator) value (before save)? Is there a way to explicitly set the DiscriminatorColumn? Haven't seen a possibility to do this yet.

Comment: @Chris thanks for your comment. Yeah, with this approach i could provide a class i want to use, but my problem is that i will not have an explicit class declaration for each possible value (type). These types can be created anytime and therefore are not fixed.

Comment: You need a combination then of this and some dynamic entities. I don't know why they wouldn't be available on the fly (unless you are dynamically creating tables, why wouldn't you have static classes to represent the datatype needed), but see https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/Dynamic

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately, no. Annotations and their parameters are resolved at compile-time.

In other words, the compiler needs this particular usage of `@DescriminatorColumn` to "know" its parameters before the instance of `Topic` containing `type_id` is ever instantiated.

For reference, here is a listing of the allowed annotation parameter types, as specified in the JLS:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.6.1

Comment: Yes, you are right. The annotation approach was more a desperate than a real attempt. What would you recommend to realise a dynamic inheritance with jpa?